# Aligning Floated Content

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using the [Twitter Bootstrap toolkit](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/index.html) to style my site. I'm implementing a split button dropdown with markup similar to the following.

```
<div class="btn-group">
    <a class="btn btn-small btn-info" href="#">
        Add New Provider
    </a>
    <a class="btn btn-info dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
        <span class="caret"></span>
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">...</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">...</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

This works as intended; however, I would like to align the entire button to the right. But the `btn-group` and `btn` classes are both floated left so any text alignment is ignored.

If I knew the total width of the button, I could set the outer `<div>` to that width and align the entire `<div>` in a parent `<div>`. But I don't know the total width.

Is there any way to align this content to the right, without reworking the underlying Bootstrap classes?

*Note: I've posted a [jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8Pjab/2/)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't guarantee this will work on your specific use-case (because I haven't tried it for myself, and I don't know exactly what markup and CSS you're using), but this does work on your jsFiddle demo:

```
.panel-container {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: right;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[jsFiddle solution](http://jsfiddle.net/8Pjab/7/)

I recommend using left/right `padding` instead of using `text-align`, although both will still work, regardless if they're being floated or not. What matters is that their widths are declared `width: auto`.

If you don't want to modify the core Bootstrap files, you can use the same classes in a separate stylesheet and override the styles from Bootstrap instead. Just ensure that the separate, personal stylesheet is called after Bootstrap. For example...

in bootstrap.css:

```
.input-mini {
    width: 60px;
}
```

in your personal-stylesheet.css:

```
/* Redefine the same style
   declared in Bootstrap */

.input-mini {
    width: 40px;
}
```

in your header:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="personal-stylesheet.css" />
```

Comment: I had a little trouble following that since you rearranged the markup but it seems like you are altering the inner, underlying classes. Since these are maintained by the Twitter Bootstrap team, that was something I indicated I wanted to avoid.

Comment: [updated jsFiddle solution](http://jsfiddle.net/8Pjab/8/) Is this what you were going for then? Feel free to rename `.container` if necessary.

Comment: Unfortunately, no. It appears you are still modifying the styles of the inner, underlying `<div>`s. Although it's kind of awkward because I need to switch back and forth between my original example because of the markup changes.

Comment: I don't think I understand what it is you're asking for. The CSS doesn't interfere with Bootstrap. The selector `.container .btn` will limit its styles to `.btn`s within `.container` which means it's safe to implement throughout the site. The only div I'm styling in the example above is `.container` and that's completely customizable.

Comment: I've created [an updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8Pjab/10/) using the class names of [your originally posted jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8Pjab/2/). I've stripped out the unnecessary code to make it less confusing.

Comment: And if that's not it either, I've created [another jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8Pjab/11/) that uses inline styling (which is incredibly criminal) and doesn't modify any CSS at all.

Comment: Yes, that last one is a good one, thanks. The point was that the left and right panels were representing similar classes withing Bootstrap and I was looking for a way to leave them alone. Inline CSS helps me at this stage--it's trivial to move them into classes once it works.

Answer (score 2):

This was fixed in bootstrap 2.0.2.  Use the bootstrap class "pull-right"

https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/2045

http://jsbin.com/ebemiz/2/edit#html,live